# Position PointText in Center of Canvas

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I need this:

```
var text = new PointText({
    point: [50, 50],
    content: 'Text',
    fillColor: 'black',
    fontFamily: 'Courier New',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 25
});
```

to be centered (x + y) in my canvas.

There is nothing special about the canvas.

Comment: where is the problem or the question ? The thing is to take canvasWidth-label/2 as X origin and same for heigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `view` object stores a `center` property which represents it's centre.
So if you do this:

```
var text = new PointText({
  position: view.center,
  content: 'Text',
  fillColor: 'black',
  fontFamily: 'Courier New',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: 25
});
```

It will be positioned in the centre of your canvas.

Here's the [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/TY7BCoJAEIZfZdiLBdIh6LLRSegYgUGH7LCuUw6uO7JuWonv3koRzu37v5nhH4RVNQop0gq9LkUsNBcTd8qBx6eHHVjs4chk/SnwYsgshGm4JU9sJXSE/Uqj9ejir9McwHoJ0XQR/dIbGZOwYRfy3Chd/UVY36uazCuYhB+O0MEB+7k/I93L6WPOppiLlN4oYb3J7Ljchvq5Q1U1U9tWyMt1/AA=) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a more precise positionning, consider centering your text using `justification: 'center'` and adding a small vertical offset proportional to font size.

```
var text = new PointText({
    position: view.center + [0,5],
    justification: 'center',
    content: 'Text',
    fillColor: 'blue',
    fontFamily: 'Courier New',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 25
});
```

See this [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/rVJNS8NAEP0rSy6pGIIUeol4KngqIlbw0PSw2UybMduZsJk0aul/d7cfElCUgnt782bfe7Ozu4j0BqIsmtcgpoqSyHAZ8FY7xQ7XSNo+w5uoO0XQq0dGkoBHu5yUPw23KMiUqS1CnxogAZccOcMekGQqDjfiU3WF1k7ZsvP1wmpTfxG+/V5v0L57ZsqdQ3DqAfoh/wK4roJiwbYcEnP8gEyNJzntr25zyikMUKJesx/gHF5Llc6QYHTIWnBHZZsKNzNYSaKGxYJFePMUzILcWShtxXENh/heNHZQxt/cxn/ZHWR/8gs5hnbjX/0MOwdGoLx4P+paLW6SyfL0fq9dK7hCo4+N8bEpvmCLHfz/Ev1fLBzougkjtVG2WO4/AQ==) for a demonstration.